# this.method return undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

```
function Z(params) {
    for (var j in params) {
        this[j] = params[j];
    }
}

Z.prototype = {
    show: function () {
        var _this = this;
        $(window).bind('resize', this.adjust); // Return undefined? Why? 
       //$(window).bind('resize',function(){
       // _this.adjust(); // This works.
       //});
    },
    adjust: function () {
        alert(this.id);
    }
}

var a = new Z({
    id: 5
});
a.show();
```

Hello, why this.adjust return undefined? But its working when anonymous function is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript closures, the `this` keyword is late binding. Which means it is not evaluated until the function is actually called.

So when the "resize" event is fired your context is already gone.

Assigning the value to a variable then using that variable inside a function creates a **closure**. As long as that function is referenced somewhere it will retain the value of `_this`.

`_this` in your example uses early binding while `this` uses late binding. At the time that your resize event handler is called the value of `this` will be the window object which obviously doesn't have a method `adjust`

See also: http://javascript.info/tutorial/binding

Comment: I think that to use `bind(...)` and `apply(...)` like in the article you would have to past the prototype code into your Javascript. But I wouldn't, I think they add unnecessary complexity in this case. I would actually do it using straight closures the exact way you did in your question. The `bind(...)` method just allows you to dynamically override `this` which is useful if you are making a very large app with tons of events but not as useful in a simple example like this.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `this` in `alert(this.id);` is refering to the `window` object now and not to your `a` instance.

Answer (score 1):

This a "this" scope issue. Try replacing the statement:

```
$(window).bind('resize', this.adjust);
```

by this:

```
$(window).bind('resize', _this.adjust);
```